# Alternate SVG fill color on click

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I am trying to have an SVG filled when someone clicks on a certain path then have the fill color reset to default when someone clicks the second time, I have successfully added the ability to fill with color when clicked but have been having issues resetting the fill color to default on the second click; below is the code I have currently, it works the opposite, instead of fill color be applied on the first click and reset on the second click, it instead resets the fill color on the first click and applies the fill color on second click which is the opposite of my desirable outcome.

```
jQuery('#color-my-svg').on("click", function() {
  if(!jQuery(this)[0].hasAttribute('style')){
    jQuery('#color-my-svg').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
  }
  else{
    jQuery(this).removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

I would like to achieve the desired result of applying fill color on click then resetting the fill color on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

**check this it might help you**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  #mysvg{
   fill:red;
  }
  #mysvg.color-swatcher{
   fill:green;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-alert-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="12"></line><line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="16"></line></svg>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#mysvg').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('color-swatcher');
   })
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```